# Listview custom adapter convertView inconsistency

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to create a listview with header by using ArrayAdapter. The header shows the date of the normal rows successfully upon loading. I'm interchanging to xmls depending on the condition. However, when I try to scroll it up, the convertView returns null and sometimes not null. Why is this happening?

```
private Context context;
private ArrayList<MapExtension> mapValues;
private LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> dateLinkedHashMap;

ListViewAdapter_4(Context context, LinkedHashMap<Integer, MapExtension> mapValues) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_listview_layout_3_header, mapValues.keySet().toArray());
    this.context = context;

    this.mapValues= new ArrayList<>();
    this.mapValues.addAll(mapValues.values());

    this.dateLinkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView lblStudentName;
    TextView lblStudentNumber;
    TextView lblDateSection;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    ViewHolder mViewHolder;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.US);
    String newDateStr = "";

    if (convertView == null) {
        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        if (dateLinkedHashMap.size() == 0) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_layout_3_header, parent, false);
            mViewHolder.lblDateSection = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblDateSection);
        } else {

            newDateStr = dateFormat.format(getDate(mapValues.get(position).getDate()));

            if (dateLinkedHashMap.containsValue(newDateStr)) {

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_layout_3, parent, false);

                mViewHolder.lblStudentName= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblStudentName);
                mViewHolder.lblStudentNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblStudentNumber );

            } else {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_layout_3_header, parent, false);

                mViewHolder.lblDateSection = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblDateSection);
            }
        }

        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {

        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    MapExtension me = mapValues.get(position);

    String name = me.getStudentName();
    String number = me.getStudentNumber();

    if(mViewHolder.lblStudentName != null &&  mViewHolder.lblStudentNumber != null) {
        mViewHolder.lblStudentName.setText(name);
        mViewHolder.lblStudentNumber.setText(number);               
    }

    // this block works fine earlier in regaining the position of the date
    // but when the problem occurred, it never worked again.
    if(mViewHolder.lblDateSection != null) {

        newDateStr = dateFormat.format(getDate(date));

        if (dateLinkedHashMap.size() == 0) {
            mViewHolder.lblDateSection.setText(newDateStr);
            dateLinkedHashMap.put(position, newDateStr);
        } else {
            if (dateLinkedHashMap.containsValue(newDateStr)) {
                if (dateLinkedHashMap.containsKey(position)) {
                    mViewHolder.lblDateSection.setText(newDateStr);
                } else {
                    mViewHolder.lblDateSection.setText("");
                }
            } else {
                mViewHolder.lblDateSection.setText(newDateStr);
                dateLinkedHashMap.put(position, newDateStr);
            }
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Based on what you are trying to do, I think you should be using checking for convertView == null but also use the position parameter. Probably take a look at Jeff Sharkey's Separated List Adapter http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

Answer (score 0):

If the View which represents a row is no longer visible the getView() method reuses it via the convertView parameter to show another element.

For ptimization adapter assigns the new data to the convertView rather than inflating a new one.

In case no View is available for reuse, null will be sent as the convertView parameter in the get view method which needs to be checked in the viewHolder implementation